# Absolute jump with a PC relative data source (AArch64)

Tags: assembly, arm64

How may one perform an absolute jump (64-bit dword) on *AArch64* with as few instructions as possible, whilst using a data source relative to the program counter?

At first glance, one may assume a `LDR` followed by a  `BR` is possible, i.e:

```
LDR x9, [PC, #0x8];
BR x9
.dword 0xBADC0FFEE0DDF00D
```

But since `PC` is no longer a general purpose register on *AArch64*, it is not.

So how can this be done with as few instructions as possible?

Comment: if you read the documentation it tells you it is a pc-relative load, the pc is just not encoded in the instruction, it is implied in this instruction set.

Comment: I see, that's why I was confused. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: "Load Register (literal) calculates an address from the PC value and an immediate offset, loads a word from memory, and writes it to a register."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rely on the compiler generated literal pools as usual:

```
LDR x9, =0xBADC0FFEE0DDF00D
BR x9
```

This is readable and will essentially generate the same code.

If you want to have precise control, you can use the `LDR literal` version, the manual says:

> Load Register (literal) calculates an address from the PC value and an immediate offset, loads a word from memory, and writes it to a register.

As such you can do:

```
LDR x9, foo
BR x9
foo: .dword 0xBADC0FFEE0DDF00D
```

Or less readable but without a label:

```
LDR x9, .+8
BR x9
.dword 0xBADC0FFEE0DDF00D
```